# NSURLSession delegates on UI thread with NSOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I got challenged to use the NSURLSession delegates to update a UI element (just a label) with the status of the download, but I can only use NSOperation and not `dispatch_get_main_queue`

I'm not even sure this is possible to call the UI thread with NSOperation directly (and not a completion block), but I thought of ask here to see if anyone knows if this is possible.

In a nutshell, this is what I have with the C calls to dispatch_async:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
      downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
      didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten
 totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten
totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
    long percentage = (totalBytesWritten * 100) / totalBytesExpectedToWrite;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
       ^{
           self.label_bytesExpected.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Expected = %lld", totalBytesExpectedToWrite];
           self.label_bytesWritten.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Received = %lld (%ld%%)", totalBytesWritten, percentage];
       });
}
```

Is it possible to call NSOperation (queue or block or anything else with it) to display this on the UI instead of using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. You should use `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`

> **+ (NSOperationQueue *)mainQueue**
>
> Returns the operation queue associated with the main thread.

So your code could be:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        self.label_bytesExpected.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Expected = %lld", totalBytesExpectedToWrite];
        self.label_bytesWritten.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Received = %lld (%ld%%)", totalBytesWritten, percentage];
    }];
```

Comment: Ah that's how  you use the mainQueue operation. Thanks! (now I need to wait to accept your answer...)

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLSession` has a property called `delegateQueue` which indicates on which queue delegate's methods will be called. It can be set to `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` via factory method:

`[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration
                              delegate:delegate
                          delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];`

Comment: right, but that's only when you setup the session and not when you get a callback to the delegates